# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 562: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: unicode, encode, python-unicode

i'm having problems working in a python version 2.6.6. I explain why I use this version: I'm working with a program created several years ago (find the project here https://github.com/danthedeckie/OpenLP-To-ProPresenter5-Converter) . In short, the program takes a dqlite database and converts it into a proprietary database of the ProPresenter program. The problem is that I get a Unicode error that I can't resolve: [error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/braYo.png)
I have reason to believe the error is on line 351.
I attach the file, if you solve it a huge thank you.
There is also a db test if you want to try.. [sqlite db for try](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YQUWb00xvN9sz1dB0PzFBT2-SptXHWkk/view?usp=share_link)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#############################################################################
#                                                                           #
#                      OpenLP to ProPresentor Converter                     #
#                    (C) 2012 Daniel Fairhead, OMNIvision                   #
#                                                                           #
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#                                                                           #
# This program is free to use, change, edit, do what you want with.         #
# Please consider a donation to OMNIvision if you find it useful. :-)       #
#                                                                           #
# http://www.omnivision.om.org/                                             #
#                                                                           #
# OMNIvision is the media & events team of Operation Mobilisation (OM)      #
#                                                                           #
# http://www.om.org/                                                        #
#                                                                           #
#############################################################################

# Configuration Options:

OPENLP_DATABASE = r"C:\Users\Daniele Uni\Downloads\Telegram Desktop\songs.sqlite"
OUTPUT_DIRECTORY = "C:/Users/Daniele/Downloads"


DEFAULT_FONT = "Helvetica"
DEFAULT_COLOR = ('255', '255', '255')  # RGB, white.
BACKGROUND_COLOR = '0 0 0 1'     # RGBA black.

MAX_LINES = 4

OPEN_DIR_ON_EXIT = True  # If you want to open the dir of new files...

# Options you probably don't need to edit, but can easily enough:
MAX_VERSE_COLORS = 14               # Number of defined colors for verses
VERSE_COLORS = ['0 0 1 1',    # 0 = Blue
                '0 1 0 1',    # 1 = Green
                '1 0.5 0 1',  # 2 = Orange
                '1 0 1 1',    # 3 = Purple
                '0 1 1 1',    # 4 = Yellow
                '0.5 1 0 1',  # ...
                '1 1 0.5 1',
                '0 0 1 1',
                '0 1 0 1',
                '1 0.5 0 1',
                '1 0 1 1',
                '0 1 1 1',
                '0.5 1 0 1',
                '1 1 0.5 1']

CHORUS_COLOR = '1 0 0 1'

VERBOSE_NAMES = {'c': 'Chorus',
                 'v': 'Verse',
                 'b': 'Bridge',
                 'e': 'Ending',
                 'p': 'Pre-Chorus'}

# Cramming everything into this one file as opposed to separating it out
# into modules may be rather messy and bad practice.  I do apologise.
# My intention is to have this as a stand alone python script, to make
# it as easy as possible to distribute.

import sqlite3 as sql            # To import from OpenLP
import os                        # File loading stuff.
import sys                       # For UTF-8 settings.
try:
    # Python 2: "reload" is built-in
    reload
except NameError:
    from importlib import reload
                                 #    wasn't loaded originally.
sys.stdout.encoding
'UTF-8'  #    Oh for Py3k everywhere.

import re                        # For regexy stuff.
import xml.parsers.expat         # For Parsing OpenLP Lyrics Data

from base64 import b64encode     # For ProPresenter RTF Data blobs
from uuid import uuid1           # For ProPresenter Slide UUIDs
from datetime import datetime    # Guess.

# Apparently it's faster / better to compile regex:

__re_uni_x = re.compile(r'\\x..')      # Unicode \x form
__re_uni_u = re.compile(r'\\u....')    # Unicode \u form
__re_year = re.compile(r'^\d\d\d\d')   # Year from Copyright String
__re_xml_attr = re.compile('[<>\n"]')  # Stuff to strip from XML attributes

###################################################
#
# Short generic(ish) useful functions:
#
###################################################


def xml_attr(text):
    return (re.sub(__re_xml_attr,
            ' ',
            text.replace('&', '&amp;').replace('"', '&quot;')) if text != None else '')


def make_uuid():
    return uuid1().__str__().upper()


def Verbose_names(key):
    # Could use a collections.defaultdict, but I can't be bothered right now.
    if key in VERBOSE_NAMES:
        return VERBOSE_NAMES[key]
    else:
        return key


# Stupid BLASTED RTF.  This took me a *very* long time to figure out,
# and I'm not sure it's in any way anything like bullet proof now anyway.
# At least it works for our database, currently.
# I *never* want to work with RTF again.



def AntiUnicode(text):

    def escape_u(t):
#        """ turns a '\u####' type hexadecimal unicode escape char into
#            it's RTF '\uxxxx' decimal.
#           For use in a re.sub function as the callback. """
#        return r'\u' + unicode(int(t.group()[2:], 16)) + ' '
        return r'\u' + unicode(int(t.group()[2:], 16)) + ' '

    return re.sub(__re_uni_x,   escape_u,
               re.sub(__re_uni_u, escape_u,
                   text.encode('unicode-escape')))\
           .replace(r'\n','\\\n')


def MakeRTFBlob(text):
    return b64encode(
             '{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\cocoartf1038\\cocoasubrtf360\n{\\fonttbl\\f0\\fswiss\\fcharset0 '+DEFAULT_FONT+';}\n' 
           + '{\\colortbl;\\red'+DEFAULT_COLOR[0]+'\\green'+DEFAULT_COLOR[1]+'\\blue'+DEFAULT_COLOR[2]+';}\n'
           + '\\pard\\tx560\\tx1120\\tx1680\\tx2240\\tx2800\\tx3360\\tx3920\\tx4480\\tx5040\\tx5600\\tx6160\\tx6720\\qc\\pardirnatural\n\n'
           + '\\f0\\fs102\\fsmilli51200 \\cf1 \\expnd0\\expndtw0\\kerning0\n\\outl0\\strokewidth-20 \\strokec0 \\uc0 ' + AntiUnicode(text) + '}')


########################
#
# XML sections. (To be written to ProPresenter files)
#
########################

# This is messy, and there is no way to help it,
# besides having a separate template file.


def VerseBlock(block_name, block_type, text_sections, color='0 0 0 0'):

    def list_split_substrings_by_lines(max_lines, oldlist):
        # Very imperative, I know.  There's probably a better
        # (functional/pythonic) way to do this...
        new_list = []
        for raw_item in oldlist:
            x = 1
            new_item = ''
            for line in raw_item.splitlines():
                if x < max_lines:
                    new_item += line + '\n'
                    x += 1
                else:
                    new_item += line
                    new_list.append(new_item)
                    new_item = ''
                    x = 1
            if new_item != '':
                new_list.append(new_item)

        new_list.reverse()  # Not sure why reverse is needed...
        return new_list

    def list_split_substrings(split_by, oldlist):
        newlist = []
        for item in oldlist:
            newlist += item.split(split_by)
        return newlist

    all_sections = map(unicode.strip(
                       list_split_substrings_by_lines(MAX_LINES,  
                           list_split_substrings('\n\n', 
                               list_split_substrings ('[---]', 
                                   text_sections)))))

    return ('<RVSlideGrouping name="' + block_name + '" uuid="' + make_uuid()
           + '" color="' + color + '" serialization-array-index="0"><slides containerClass="NSMutableArray">'
           + ''.join(map(SlideBlock, all_sections))
           + '</slides></RVSlideGrouping>')

def SlideBlock(text):
    return '<RVDisplaySlide backgroundColor="' + BACKGROUND_COLOR + '" enabled="1" highlightColor="0 0 0 0" hotKey="" label="" notes="" slideType="1" sort_index="0" UUID="' + make_uuid() + '" drawingBackgroundColor="0" chordChartPath="" serialization-array-index="0"><cues containerClass="NSMutableArray"></cues><displayElements containerClass="NSMutableArray"><RVTextElement displayDelay="0" displayName="Default" locked="0" persistent="0" typeID="0" fromTemplate="1" bezelRadius="0" drawingFill="0" drawingShadow="1" drawingStroke="0" fillColor="0 0 0 0" rotation="0" source="" adjustsHeightToFit="0" verticalAlignment="0" RTFData="' + MakeRTFBlob(text) + '" revealType="0" serialization-array-index="0"><_-RVRect3D-_position x="30" y="30" z="0" width="964" height="708"></_-RVRect3D-_position><_-D-_serializedShadow containerClass="NSMutableDictionary"><NSNumber serialization-native-value="4" serialization-dictionary-key="shadowBlurRadius"></NSNumber><NSColor serialization-native-value="0 0 0 1" serialization-dictionary-key="shadowColor"></NSColor><NSMutableString serialization-native-value="{2.82843, -2.82843}" serialization-dictionary-key="shadowOffset"></NSMutableString></_-D-_serializedShadow><stroke containerClass="NSMutableDictionary"><NSColor serialization-native-value="0 0 0 0" serialization-dictionary-key="RVShapeElementStrokeColorKey"></NSColor><NSNumber serialization-native-value="0" serialization-dictionary-key="RVShapeElementStrokeWidthKey"></NSNumber></stroke></RVTextElement></displayElements><_-RVProTransitionObject-_transitionObject transitionType="-1" transitionDuration="1" motionEnabled="0" motionDuration="20" motionSpeed="100"></_-RVProTransitionObject-_transitionObject></RVDisplaySlide>'



def HeaderBlock(Name='New Song',
                Authors='',
                Artist='',
                CCLICopyRightInfo='',
                CCLILicenceNumber='',
                Publisher='',
                Notes=''):

    return '<RVPresentationDocument height="768" width="1024" versionNumber="500" docType="0" creatorCode="1349676880" lastDateUsed="' + datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') + '" usedCount="0" category="Song" resourcesDirectory="" backgroundColor="0 0 0 1" drawingBackgroundColor="0" notes="' + Notes + '" artist="' + Artist + '" author="' + Authors + '" album="" CCLIDisplay="0" CCLIArtistCredits="" CCLISongTitle="' + Name + '" CCLIPublisher="' + Publisher + '" CCLICopyrightInfo="' + CCLICopyRightInfo + '" CCLILicenseNumber="' + CCLILicenceNumber + '" chordChartPath=""><timeline timeOffSet="0" selectedMediaTrackIndex="0" unitOfMeasure="60" duration="0" loop="0"><timeCues containerClass="NSMutableArray"></timeCues><mediaTracks containerClass="NSMutableArray"></mediaTracks></timeline><bibleReference containerClass="NSMutableDictionary"></bibleReference><_-RVProTransitionObject-_transitionObject transitionType="-1" transitionDuration="1" motionEnabled="0" motionDuration="20" motionSpeed="100"></_-RVProTransitionObject-_transitionObject><groups containerClass="NSMutableArray">'


#def FooterBlock():
FooterBlock = '</groups><arrangements containerClass="NSMutableArray"></arrangements></RVPresentationDocument>'



###########
#
# (OpenLP) Lyrics XML Parsing
#
###########

def ParseLyric(text):
    current_verses = []

    def _element(name, attrs):
        if name == 'verse':
            current_verses.append(attrs)
            current_verses[-1]['text'] = []

    def _chardata(data):
        current_verses[-1]['text'].append(data)
        
    parser = xml.parsers.expat.ParserCreate()
    parser.StartElementHandler = _element
    parser.CharacterDataHandler = _chardata
    parser.buffer_text = True

    parser.Parse(text,True)

    current_verses.reverse() #Not really sure why we need this...

    return current_verses

#######
#
# Database functions:
#
#######

def filterbyfield(id,table,field='id'):
    return [row for row in table if row[field] == id]


###################################################
#
# Actually do stuff:
#
###################################################


def main():
    # First load the data from the OpenLP database:

    try:
        con = None

        # Fetch all the data first. Gets it in memory to use, rather than
        # loads of SQLlite queries. This seems to be faster, with a little 
        # profiling.  If re-writing it as loads of sqlite queries
        # works better for you, I'm cool with that too.

        print ("OpenLP to Pro-Presenter 5 converter.\n")
        print ("Loading Database:\n  "
                + os.path.expanduser(OPENLP_DATABASE) + "\n")

        con = sql.connect(os.path.expanduser(OPENLP_DATABASE))
        con.row_factory = sql.Row

        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute('SELECT id, title, ccli_number, copyright, comments, lyrics FROM songs')
        songs = cur.fetchall()
        
        cur.execute('SELECT id, display_name FROM authors')
        authors = dict()
        for author in cur.fetchall():
            authors[author['id']] = author['display_name']

        cur.execute('SELECT song_id, author_id FROM authors_songs')
        authors_songs = cur.fetchall()

        print ('  Cool.  ' + str(len(songs)) + ' songs loaded.\n' );

        # Database helper functions:
        
        def get_song_authornames(song_id):
            return ' &amp; '.join(
                [authors[id] for id in 
                    [row['author_id'] for row in authors_songs 
                        if row['song_id'] == song_id]])

    except:

        print ("Sorry - There was a problem loading the OpenLP Database.\n" +
              "(" + OPENLP_DATABASE + ")\n" +
              "Maybe OpenLP isn't set up on this user?\n\n" +
              "If you know where the database is, you can edit the path at \n" +
              "the top of this script and set it manually.")
        exit()


    # Now go through songs and output the files.

    print ("And writing the new files to\n  " + OUTPUT_DIRECTORY + "\n")

    for song in songs:

        song_authors = get_song_authornames(song['id'])

        # Find the copyright year (this would be briefer in perl...)

        get_year = re.match(__re_year, xml_attr(song['copyright']))

        if get_year != None:
            copyright_year = get_year.group()
            copyright = song['copyright'][4:].strip()
        else:
            copyright_year = ''
            copyright = ''


        # Prepare Header Block to write:

        to_write = ( HeaderBlock(Name          = xml_attr(song['title']),
                             CCLILicenceNumber = xml_attr(song['ccli_number']),
                             Notes             = xml_attr(song['comments']),
                             CCLICopyRightInfo = xml_attr(copyright_year),
                             Publisher         = xml_attr(copyright),
                             Authors           = xml_attr(song_authors)) )
        
        # Prepare Verses to write: (funny python syntax...)

        to_write += ''.join(
            [VerseBlock(Verbose_names(v['type']) + ' ' + v['label'],
                        v['type'],
                        v['text'],
                        color = CHORUS_COLOR if v['type'] == 'c'\
                                             else VERSE_COLORS[min(MAX_VERSE_COLORS-1,int(v['label']))])
            for v in ParseLyric(song['lyrics'])])

        try:
            # Now actually write the thing.
            f = open(OUTPUT_DIRECTORY + song['title'].replace('/','') + '.pro5','w')
            f.write ( to_write + FooterBlock )
            f.close()
        except:
            print ('Oh dear. Something went wrong with writing "' + song['title'] + '".\nSorry.\n\n' +
                   'Maybe it\'s a file-write permissions issue?\n' +
                   'You could try changing where this script is writing to, it\'s the line\n' +
                   '  OUTPUT_DIRECTORY="' + OUTPUT_DIRECTORY + '"\n' +
                   'that will need to be changed.' )

            try:
                f.close()
            except:
                pass

            exit();

    print ("Finished.")
    if OPEN_DIR_ON_EXIT:
        os.system('open "' + OUTPUT_DIRECTORY + '"')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the original code there was a problem (founded in issues on gitlub), I'm not an expert of programming, I tried to search online but without results. Pay attention to the versione of Py. With python 3 unicode is not supported (and also reload function). I suggest version 2.6.6

Comment: It seems that that program was programmed also for python3. Maybe you should do some adaptation (python3 changed during time, and possibly somebody did few modification on program, without thinking compatibility). -- note: you can replace "unicode" with "str" in most parts. The last part may be more tricky

Comment: No, I did some edit for readapte the code and try it on py3 (for example I edit the expression for reload ).
About unicode, it is true what you said but I've problem with this expression (    all_sections = map(unicode.strip(
                       list_split_substrings_by_lines(MAX_LINES,  
                           list_split_substrings('\n\n', 
                               list_split_substrings ('[---]', 
                                   text_sections)))))
)
For this I returned into 2.6.6 version of py.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It is just a line. I think you can easily rewrite it. `unicode.strip` should be `str.strip`. And then look for further errors. It is since many years that it is easier to rewrite to python3 instead of going back to all complexities with encoding in python2 (we almost forgot all subtleties of that time).